# How to find why and which microservice is slow?

Tags: microservices

In one of my recent interview in Sapient, interview asked few questions:

**Q1**: How to find which microservice is slow, if your query goes to multiple services?

**Q2**. How to use logs in microservices and which information you will display in logs?

If anybody has any answer, then please explain.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Based on generality, for the first one you can follow circuit breaker patterns for this, where you can mention timeouts on the called methods, such that if they don't respond till a threshold then the fallback methods shall be used to return some mock object of the kind of data being expected from the called method.

There are frameworks for this in Spring like Resilience4j or Hystrix

For logging you can use distributed tracing, i.e. via Zipkins ( an offering in spring cloud again ). And its purely your choice on what has to be logged for your application

And if dealing in Kubernetes based environments then you can use Jaeger also for distributed tracing and Istio can be used for service mesh and circuit breakers.

Hope this turns up useful !!